# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.infura.io

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, infura

I got this error when deploy my contract.

It never happened using rinkeby testnet same key, same project.

I got this error 3 time and

I already spend $3000 ETH for this error

How can I predict this damn error?

```
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.infura.io',
    data: { originalError: [Object] },
    stack: 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.infura.io\n' +
      '    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)'
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.infura.io',
  data: {
    originalError: {
      errno: -3008,
      code: 'ENOTFOUND',
      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
      hostname: 'mainnet.infura.io'
    }
  },
  stack: 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainnet.infura.io\n' +
    '    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)'
}
```

++

curl https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/PROJECT-ID 
-X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1}'

is work well it makes hard to me